# How to add three different rectangles on three different button clicks in an array of rectangles

Tags: vb.net

```vb
    Dim arr() As Rectangle
    For i = 0 To 2
        Select Case k
           Case 1
                arr(i) = myRect
            Case 2
                arr(i) = myRect1
            Case 3
                arr(i) = myRect2
        End Select
    Next
```

I have three rectangles with their different sizes  on three different button clicks.I want to add every rectangle in  one array of rectangles step by step after the button is clicked.Like if i click 1st button then that array should be store in arr(0) and soon.`enter code here`How do i do it ? Here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add myrect,myRect1,myRect2 sizes to the array arr() in the order that buttons are clicked, you could made an assignement in all 3 click event and use a variable as index, something like that (pseudocode):

```
i=0 ' initialize index
1st button clicked event:
arr(i)=myrect
i=i+1

2st button clicked event:
arr(i)=myrect1
i=i+1

2st button clicked event:
arr(i)=myrect2
i=i+1
```

at some point you should reset the index in according to your workflow, if you have to restart the cycle.